# "About the result of the fraud check ticket" or "about the outcome of the fraud check ticket"?

Tags: difference

Would you tell me if there is any difference between *result* and *outcome* in the context below?

> We'll open a fraud check ticket to verify that the phone number belongs to you. About the **result**/**outcome** of it you'll be notified through a text or call.

Leaving aside word choice, does the sentences sound natural?

Comment: I'm not sure we can talk about the difference between those two words whilst "leaving aside word-choice." The first sentence needs a hyphen in _fraud-check_. Perhaps It could all be written more straightforwardly in one sentence: _....belongs to you and will call or text you (about) the result_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word order of the second sentence sounds weird. I’d say
“You’ll be notified of the result/outcome by text or phone call”.
Result or outcome are equally ok. I’m a native British speaker of English.